# Wordpress function to check if table is empty

Tags: mysql, wordpress, google-analytics, mediatemple

I am running a WP blog on MediaTemple WP Hosting. They provide a built-in function to integrate Google Analytics code. As I need to make some changes to the GA tracking code in order to anonymize the users IP, I want to disable that function and replace it with custom one.

Here is the MT built-in function:

```
    public function add_ga_tracking_snippet_to_head()
{
    if ( get_option( $this->plugin->name . '_web_property_id_head' ) !== false ) {
        $web_property_id = get_option( $this->plugin->name . '_web_property_id_head' );
?>
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', '<?php echo $web_property_id ?>', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
<?php
    }
}
```

and here is the screenshot of the db table where GA ID is stored:
[image]

Now, if I delete the ID inside the option_value table, the function should not print any `<script>...</script>`, because of the conditional statement
    `if ( get_option( $this->plugin->name . '_web_property_id_head' ) !== false )` but it doesn't work this way.

Here's what I get instead:

[image]

P.S. I've even tried to alter the function with `isset` and `!empty` with no success. Where am I wrong?

Comment: Can you show me the result of this: `var_dump(get_option( $this->plugin->name . '_web_property_id_head' ));`

Comment: @tuananh the result is `string(13) "UA-516XXXXX-X`

Comment: So it's not empty. Therefore none of your solutions work. You need to make sure this function return empty string.

Answer (score 0):

The line `get_option( $this->plugin->name . '_web_property_id_head' )` must be `false` for that conditional to not execute.

Empty strings and `NULL` in MySQL aren't boolean values so they're never going to `!== false`.

Comment: If you mean to type `false` into the table, here's the result:
`ga('create', 'false', 'auto');
 ga('send', 'pageview');`

Comment: I think that's the string `'false'`, not the boolean value `false`. My point is obviously the condition resolving to true, so clearly whatever `get_option()` is returning is not the boolean value `false`.

Comment: So what you would recommend? To change the function's conditional statement in order to make it correctly work? If so, would you mind to provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, MT core plugin needs to be revised in order to work fine. Here's the fix:

```
if ( get_option( $this->plugin->name . '_web_property_id_head' ) !== '' ) {
```

I've opened a ticket on MT support where I asked them to officially fix that function.